# Strange error reading files from a directory in Java

Tags: java, filesystems

**EDIT:** children is an array of directories. This code loops trough this array in order to enter to each directory and load into the array *webs* all the files listed. Then, for each file, the readFile function is supposed to read the file.

My code is:

```
for (File cat: children) {
    File[] webs = cat.listFiles();
    System.out.println("  Indexing category: " + cat.getName());
    for (File f: webs) {                    
        Web w = readFile(f);                
       // Do things with w  
    }   
}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
org.htmlparser.util.ParserException: Error in opening a connection to 209800.webtrec
209801.webtrec
     ...     
422064.webtrec
422071.webtrec
422087.webtrec
422089.webtrec
422112.webtrec
422125.webtrec
422127.webtrec
;
java.io.IOException: File Name Too Long
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.canonicalize0(Native Method)
at java.io.UnixFileSystem.canonicalize(UnixFileSystem.java:172)
at java.io.File.getCanonicalPath(File.java:576)
at org.htmlparser.http.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:848)
at org.htmlparser.Parser.setResource(Parser.java:398)
at org.htmlparser.Parser.<init>(Parser.java:317)
at org.htmlparser.Parser.<init>(Parser.java:331)
at IndexGenerator.IndexGenerator.readFile(IndexGenerator.java:156)
at IndexGenerator.IndexGenerator.main(IndexGenerator.java:101)
```

It's strange because I don't see any of those files in that directory.

Thanks!

**EDIT2:** This is the readFile function. It loads the contents of the file into a string and parses it. Actually, files are html files.

```
private static Web readFile(File file) {
    try {           
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(file);
        FileChannel fch = fin.getChannel();

        // map the contents of the file into ByteBuffer
        ByteBuffer byteBuff = fch.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 
                0, fch.size());

        // convert ByteBuffer to CharBuffer
        // CharBuffer chBuff = Charset.defaultCharset().decode(byteBuff);
        CharBuffer chBuff = Charset.forName("UTF-8").decode(byteBuff);
        String f = chBuff.toString();

        // Close imputstream. By doing this you close the channel associated to it
        fin.close();            

        Parser parser = new Parser(f);          
        Visitor visit = new Visitor();
        parser.visitAllNodesWith((NodeVisitor)visit);           
        return new Web(visit.getCat(), visit.getBody(), visit.getTitle());

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParserException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: What is `children` ? Where does it come from ? What is `readFile` ? Show us its source code. What is it suppose to do ?

Comment: Can you print the name of the file for which the exception is thrown?

Comment: What is your Java version? If you're really not having too long named files, you could try to update your Java, this could be a bug as well.

Comment: I thought that the name was the whole list of files... I'll try to do that, thanks!

Comment: @Kits89 you should show the content of `readFile`, because that is were the exception occurs.

Comment: @hage: Oh, ok! I edited and post the code.

Comment: mmh, may be the problem is the codification of one file..

Comment: the name of the file is: 209800.webtrec and it doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

Okay, finally I got the solution.

It was a very stupid error. I had a file in that directory that contained the names of all empty html files that I had deleted in a previous task. So, I was trying to parse it, and then the parser would interpret it like an URL and not as an htmlfile (since there aren't tags and a lot of points...). I couldn't find the file easily because I have millions of files in that folder.